# Função Hide/Show não funciona no IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Tenho um JavaScript que faz a função de agrupar itens em uma tabela.

Por exemplo clico nele e ele expande trazendo mais valores desse item. O problema é que no **IE 8** não funciona. No Chrome e Mozilla a função funciona normalmente.

```
function ocultarColunasNaoAgrupadas(){
    $('#tabelaPainelCnab tbody tr td').each(function() {
        var idCell = $(this).attr('name');

        if (idCell == 'identQuebraMes') {
            var cellTextMes = ''+ $(this).html();
        }     
        if (idCell == 'identQuebraCarteira') {
            if ($(this).html().length > 0 ) {
                $(this).closest('tr').attr('agrupador', 'N');
                //$(this).closest('tr').slideToggle(300)
                $(this).closest('tr').hide();
            } else { 
                $(this).closest('tr').hide();
                $(this).closest('tr').attr('agrupador', 'S');
                $(this).closest('tr').attr('class', 'header');
                $(this).closest('tr').show();
            }  
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Seria bom especificar qual a versão do IE. Uma formatadinha no código também não faria mal =)

Comment: Estou aprendendo a usar o stack , me perdoe os erros, versao do IE 8, obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: Note que tenho 3 perguntas, responda todas por favor: 1. Ocorre algum erro no console do IE8? 2. Está usando qual versão do jQuery? 3. Tem como postar uma estrutura simplificada da parte HTML?

Comment: Boa noite guilherme, não ocorre nehum erro no IE8, Versao Jquery-1.6.2.js, Segue codigo aqui https://paste.ofcode.org/h7D5652nR2A2ignaCvHG4t

Answer (score 1):

O jQuery atual não da Suporte ao IE 8

### **Navegadores suportado**

**Desktop**

Chrome: (Current - 1) and Current

 Edge: (Current - 1) and Current

 Firefox: (Current - 1) and Current

Internet Explorer: 9+

Safari: (Current - 1) and Current

Opera: Current

**Mobile**

Stock browser on Android 4.0+
Safari on iOS 7+

### Solução

Se você precisa de suporte a navegadores mais antigos como o Internet Explorer 6-8, Opera 12.1x ou Safari 5.1+, [use jQuery 1.12](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/#jquery-all-1.x)

Comentários condicionais

```
 <!--[if IE 8]>
<script src="js/jQuery-1.12.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

fonte: http://jquery.com/browser-support/